# React map function - return one item at random

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array and I would like to display one item from the array at random within my render function. Here's what I have now which shows all items:

```
render() {
    return (
        <article className="rand-product-cont">
            {this.state.products && this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
            <article key={index} className="rand-product">
                <h3>"{product.name}"</h3>
            </article>
            ))}
        </article>
    );
};
```

How can I modify this to show only one product from the array at random? I tried this based on another question I found but it seems to display the same product every time:

```
render() {
    const product = this.state.products.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).slice(0, 1);
    return (
        <article className="rand-product-cont">
            {product && product.map((product, index) => (
            <article key={index} className="rand-product">
                <h3>"{product.name}"</h3>
            </article>
            ))}
        </article>
    );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: If you just want one value, then `.map()` should not be involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your random generator works like charm. The issue is how you render the product what your code picked from `products` array.

Try the following without `map`:

```
render() {
    const product = this.state.products.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random())
                                       .find(() => true);

    return (
        <article className="rand-product-cont">
            {product &&
                <article className="rand-product">
                    <h3>"{product.name}"</h3>
                </article>
            }
        </article>
    );
};
```

The above solution is using similar approach what I have here, representing `products` array with only number values, `find` returns the first element, so you don't need to use indexer on `products` array:

```js
const array = [12,23,43,45,34,22,77];
const element = array.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random())
                     .find(() => true);

console.log(element);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I think this is close to what I need. However when I do this nothing is being displayed and I think it's because `product` is still an array with one item. Can I just do `{product[0].name}`?

Comment: That's true, `sort` returns an array. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @user13286 I have change a bit, removed `slice` and added `find` method which gives you back the first product from the sorted array.

Comment: Something strange I noticed is that when I resize my browser window, the random product that is being displayed is changing in real-time. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? The page should pick a single product at random on load and it should continue displaying that same product until the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one element and if it's going to be random. I don't see point of using map at all

```
  function getRandomElFromArray(arrayLenght) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength);
  }

  <article ...
    {
      product && product.length > 0 &&
      product[getRandomElFromArray(product.length)]
    }
  </article>
```